# Unnecessary padding or margin on View [Android/Kotlin]

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I dont know where i am going wrong and where i mistake

I capture layout using layout inspector

> **XML FILE OF MY VIEW**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package.MyView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"

    android:background="#FFF"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    app:cardElevation="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10" android:padding="4dp"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</package.MyView>
```

> **MyView.kt**

```
class MyView :RelativeLayout
{
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()

        /*var Anim:Animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.context,R.anim.card_flip_left_in)
        this.animation=animation
        animation.start()*/
       // this.setPadding(10,10,10,10)
                val animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.context, R.anim.slide_right_in)
                animation.startOffset = 0
                this@MyView.startAnimation(animation)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow()

    }
}
```

> **slide_right_in.xml** Animation File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

Problem : i cant figure out why its adding margin or padding on top and bottom on Cardview Background when background getting Draw....

Testing Done : Emulator and Real Device Vivo V7 Plus

[image]

The Problem is **card view getting unnecessary padding or margin on top and left**

[image]

MyView size as expected....

[image]

**CardView size As expected but here the background drawing at wrong position as u can figure out in above image**

Comment: try to remove padding from top MyView android:padding="10dp"

Comment: @MustafaBohra thanks for your comment sir i will try

Comment: @MustafaBohra same output sir

Comment: Please share R.anim.slide_right_in file

Comment: @MoFaizanShaikh sure sir